# Contains statement not returning specific string

Tags: java, vector, attributes, contains

Need some help with a contains statement. After logging into my application, I am authenticating attributes for a user ID.

This works great in our test environment, but when we go to production, I am not seeing the attributes for the id. The different between test and production is that in test, we use a test id that has two attributes - Read and Write. In production, we use our id, which has many more attributes associated with it.

The code is below. I have inserted some println's to try to help find out where the code is going. In production, the line with `//4` is printing all the attributes (including the 2 listed in the code) but it never comes out of that block of code to get to `//5`.

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
    private Hashtable hashtable;
    private String url;

    private String searchBase;
    private Log vmsLogger;

    public void destroy() {}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        if (vmsLogger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            vmsLogger.info("** Pre-login filter check **");
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        if (vmsLogger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            vmsLogger.info("** Post-login filter check **");
        }

        try {
            Subject callerSubject;
            WSCredential callerCred;

            callerSubject = WSSubject.getCallerSubject();

            if (callerSubject != null) {
                callerCred = (WSCredential) callerSubject.getPublicCredentials(WSCredential.class).iterator().next();

                callerCred.set("SpecialRole", "AutoAgent");
                //System.out.println("callerCred = " + callerCred);
                getAttributes(req, callerCred);
            }
        } catch (WSSecurityException wse) {
            wse.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (vmsLogger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            vmsLogger.info("** Post-login filter check end **");
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        vmsLogger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass().getName());
    }

    private String getLDAPUrl(){

        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("authenticate.properties");
        //System.out.println("AuthProperties = " + inputStream);

        Properties props  = new Properties();
        try {
            props.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String url;

        String serverName = props.getProperty("SERVER");
        String port = props.getProperty("PORT");

        url =  "ldap://" + serverName + ":" + port;
        //System.out.println("props = " + props);
        //System.out.println("url = " + url);

        return url;
    }

    private void getAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, WSCredential cred) {
        try {
            intialize(cred);

            String attribute = "memberOf";
            String[] attrIDs = new String[] { attribute };
            Hashtable hshtbl = new Hashtable();

            hshtbl = authWithData(cred.getUniqueSecurityName(), cred.getSecurityName(), request
                    .getParameter("j_password"), attrIDs);

            Vector attributeValues = new Vector();

            if ((hshtbl != null) && hshtbl.containsKey(attribute)) {
                attributeValues = (Vector) hshtbl.get(attribute);
                System.out.println("12 hshtbl not null = " + attributeValues);   //3
                //System.out.println("attribute attrIDs = " + attrIDs);
            }

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();

            if (attributeValues != null) {
                System.out.println("attributeValues not null = " + attributeValues);    //4
                if (attributeValues.
                    attributeValues.contains("CN=nw-PPARead,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIE,DC=NET") ||
                    attributeValues.contains("CN=nw-PPARead,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIEPILOT,DC=NET") ||     
                    attributeValues.contains("CN=nw-PPAWrite,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIE,DC=NET")||
                    attributeValues.contains("CN=nw-PPAWrite,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIEPILOT,DC=NET"))  {
                    //Not getting to below statement
                    System.out.println("AttributeValues out of first if" + attributeValues);   //5
                    session.setAttribute("privPPA", Boolean.TRUE);   

                    if (attributeValues.contains("CN=nw-PPAWrite,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIE,DC=NET") ||
                        attributeValues.contains("CN=nw-PPAWrite,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIEPILOT,DC=NET"))  {
                        userInfo.setPrivPPAWrite(Boolean.TRUE);
                    } else {
                        userInfo.setPrivPPAWrite(Boolean.FALSE);
                    }

                    if (attributeValues.contains("CN=nw-PPARead,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIE,DC=NET") ||
                        attributeValues.contains("CN=nw-PPARead,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIEPILOT,DC=NET"))   {
                        userInfo.setPrivPPARead(Boolean.TRUE);
                        System.out.println("2 TuserReadInfo = true");
                    } else {
                        userInfo.setPrivPPARead(Boolean.FALSE);
                    }                   
                }

                if (attributeValues.contains("BoatRead") || attributeValues.contains("BoatWrite")) {
                    session.setAttribute("privBoat", Boolean.TRUE);

                    if (attributeValues.contains("BoatWrite")) {
                        userInfo.setPrivBoatWrite(Boolean.TRUE);
                    } else {
                        userInfo.setPrivBoatWrite(Boolean.FALSE);
                    }

                    if (attributeValues.contains("BoatRead")) {
                        userInfo.setPrivBoatRead(Boolean.TRUE);
                    } else {
                        userInfo.setPrivBoatRead(Boolean.FALSE);
                    }
                }

                if (attributeValues.contains("MotorCycleRead") || attributeValues.contains("MotorCycleWrite")) {
                    session.setAttribute("privMotorCycle", Boolean.TRUE);

                    if (attributeValues.contains("MotorCycleWrite")) {
                        userInfo.setPrivMotorCycleWrite(Boolean.TRUE);
                    } else {
                        userInfo.setPrivMotorCycleWrite(Boolean.FALSE);
                    }

                    if (attributeValues.contains("MotorCycleRead")) {
                        userInfo.setPrivMotorCycleRead(Boolean.TRUE);
                    } else {
                        userInfo.setPrivMotorCycleRead(Boolean.FALSE);
                    }
                }

                userInfo.setUserID(request.getUserPrincipal().getName());
                session.setAttribute("userInfo", userInfo);

                System.out.println("userInfo out = " + userInfo);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex1) {
            vmsLogger.error("exception", ex1);
        }
    }

    private void intialize(WSCredential cred) throws Exception {
        //ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("VMSPPAConfig");
        // Set up default values for LDAP info
        url = getLDAPUrl();

        StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(cred.getUniqueSecurityName(), ",");
        String baseDN = "";
        String str = null;

        while (stk.hasMoreTokens()) {
            str = stk.nextToken();

            if (str.startsWith("dc=")) {
                if (baseDN.equals("")) {
                    baseDN = str;
                } else {
                    baseDN += "," + str;
                }
            }
        }

        searchBase = baseDN;

        // Set up LDAP config settings
        hashtable = new Hashtable();
        hashtable.put("java.naming.ldap.version", "3");
        hashtable.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        hashtable.put("java.naming.security.authentication", "Simple");
        hashtable.put("java.naming.security.protocol", "ssl");
        hashtable.put("java.naming.referral", "follow");
        hashtable.put("java.naming.provider.url", url);
    }

    private Hashtable authWithData(String userDN, String user, String pass, String[] attIDs) throws Exception {
        Hashtable ht1;
        NamingEnumeration namingenumeration;
        label0: {
            InitialDirContext initialdircontext = null;
            hashtable.put("java.naming.security.principal", userDN);
            hashtable.put("java.naming.security.credentials", pass);

            String uid = "CN=" + user;
            SearchControls searchcontrols = new SearchControls();
            searchcontrols.setSearchScope(2);

            //System.out.println("uid = " + uid);
            //System.out.println("userDN = " + userDN);
            //System.out.println("user = " + user);
            //System.out.println("pass = " + pass);
            //System.out.println("attIDs = " + attIDs);

            if (attIDs != null) {
                searchcontrols.setReturningAttributes(attIDs);
            }

            try {
                try {
                    initialdircontext = new InitialDirContext(hashtable);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw ex;
                }

                namingenumeration = initialdircontext.search(searchBase, uid, searchcontrols);

                if ((namingenumeration != null) && namingenumeration.hasMore()) {
                    break label0;
                }

                hashtable = null;
            } finally {
                if (initialdircontext != null) {
                    try {
                        initialdircontext.close();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        vmsLogger.error("Some internal error has occurred at this point", ex);
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }

            return hashtable;
        }

        hashtable = populateReturn(namingenumeration);
        ht1 = hashtable;
        System.out.println("ht1 Hashtable = " + ht1);    //2
        return ht1;
    }

    private Hashtable populateReturn(NamingEnumeration namingenumeration) throws Exception {
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        SearchResult searchresult = (SearchResult) namingenumeration.next();
        Attributes attributes = searchresult.getAttributes();
        String s;
        Vector vector;

        for (NamingEnumeration namingenumeration1 = attributes.getIDs(); (namingenumeration1 != null)
                && namingenumeration1.hasMore(); ht.put(s, vector)) {
            s = (String) namingenumeration1.next();
            vector = new Vector();

            int i = 0;

            for (NamingEnumeration namingenumeration2 = attributes.get(s).getAll(); (namingenumeration2 != null)
                    && namingenumeration2.hasMore(); vector.addElement((String) namingenumeration2.next())) {
                i++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("ht under Hashtable = " + ht);  //1

        if (ht.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return ht;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks wrong to me

```
if (attributeValues != null) {
            System.out.println("attributeValues not null = " + attributeValues);    //4
            if (**attributeValues.**
                attributeValues.contains("CN=nw-PPARead,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIE,DC=NET") ||
                attributeValues.contains("CN=nw-PPARead,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIEPILOT,DC=NET") ||     
                attributeValues.contains("CN=nw-PPAWrite,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIE,DC=NET")||
                attributeValues.contains("CN=nw-PPAWrite,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIEPILOT,DC=NET"))  {
                //Not getting to below statement
```

Your if statement is not returning true for any of the conditions.  try this simple test:

```
 Vector<String> attributeValues = new Vector();
    attributeValues.add("CN=nw-PPARead,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIE,DC=NET");
    if (attributeValues != null) {
        System.out.println("attributeValues not null = " + attributeValues); // 4
        if (attributeValues.contains("CN=nw-PPARead,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIE,DC=NET")
                || attributeValues
                        .contains("CN=nw-PPARead,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIEPILOT,DC=NET")
                || attributeValues
                        .contains("CN=nw-PPAWrite,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIE,DC=NET")
                || attributeValues.contains(
                        "CN=nw-PPAWrite,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIEPILOT,DC=NET")) {
            // Not getting to below statement
            System.out.println("AttributeValues out of first if" + attributeValues); // 5
        }
```

You should hit your //5 sysout, so I'd double-check the hardcoded strings you have in your IF logic.

Comment: Short of debugging it via the IDE, have you tried (perhaps it's a display issue within your console/IDE?) and instead of printing out the entire vector, just print the size (attributeValues.size()) to rule out the console not displaying correctly?  If not, I'd debug it to see what you could glean that way.

Comment: Vector<String> attributeValues = new Vector();
This will not work - error during code move:  generics are not supported in -source 1.4
(use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)

Comment: Just moved it with the
 attributeValues.add("CN=nw-PPARead,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIE,DC=NET");
    and it works.  
Took out Vector<String> though, as this isn't compatible.

This doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me yet :-)  When I print out the attributes, CN=nw-PPARead,OU=LDAP,OU=NSC Managed,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC=NWIE,DC=NET is printed along with a bunch of others.

Comment: If I had to guess, there must be something before/after the values (a space maybe?) that's causing it to fail.  Try trimming it before adding to attributeValues:  attributeValues = (Vector) hshtbl.get(attribute.trim())

Comment: Finally found it. Checked with my admin group and one letter in one of the attributes was off. Thank you so much for your help!!!